# CMake configuration error: File string cannot be read (Windows)

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmake, vtk

I'm new to VTK and I'm trying to install it on windows. When I run the configure command on CMake I receive the following error:

```
  FILE STRINGS file
  "C:/MyProjects/Microsoft-Visual-Studio/Shared/Python37_64/patchlevel.h"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/vtkWrapPython.cmake:167 (find_package)
  Utilities/Python/CMakeLists.txt:4 (include)


Found PythonLibs: C:/MyProjects/Microsoft-Visual-Studio/Shared/Python37_64/libs/python3.lib  
CMake Error at CMake/FindPythonLibs.cmake:183 (FILE):
  FILE STRINGS file
  "C:/MyProjects/Microsoft-Visual-Studio/Shared/Python37_64/patchlevel.h"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/vtkPythonWrapping.cmake:6 (find_package)
  Wrapping/PythonCore/CMakeLists.txt:2 (include)


CMake Warning at CMake/vtkPythonWrapping.cmake:14 (message):
  Python library .  mismatches python 3.7.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Wrapping/PythonCore/CMakeLists.txt:2 (include)


CMake Error at CMake/FindPythonLibs.cmake:183 (FILE):
  FILE STRINGS file
  "C:/MyProjects/Microsoft-Visual-Studio/Shared/Python37_64/patchlevel.h"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/vtkPythonWrapping.cmake:6 (find_package)
  Wrapping/Python/CMakeLists.txt:22 (include)


CMake Warning at CMake/vtkPythonWrapping.cmake:14 (message):
  Python library .  mismatches python 3.7.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Wrapping/Python/CMakeLists.txt:22 (include)


CMake Error at CMake/FindPythonLibs.cmake:183 (FILE):
  FILE STRINGS file
  "C:/MyProjects/Microsoft-Visual-Studio/Shared/Python37_64/patchlevel.h"
  cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Wrapping/Python/CMakeLists.txt:240 (find_package)


Performing Test VTK_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS_ALLOWED - Failed
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The system is: Windows - 6.3.9600 - AMD64. I have tried to run it as administrator, but nothing change. What can I do?

Comment: Will you share with us the command you are using to configure Cmake?

Comment: Also, is Python installed at `C:\MyProjects\Microsoft-Visual-Studio\Shared\Python37_64`?

Comment: You may want to ask on our discourse : https://discourse.vtk.org